# Hiding the Windows 10 "You have been signed in with a temporary profile"

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-10, windows-registry, user-profile

Unlike most people on the internet searching something related to this, I do **not** want to fix this message. In this test environment domain users are meant to have a temporary profile. I am tying to hide the message in the status bar and the, "Your not signed in" popup from the user. I cannot find a GPO or registry key to do this. Have I overlooked it or is this impossible.

Comment: Did you added the user to the local group guest to make them have temporary profile ? as if yes, it should not display that

Comment: Yes, they are added to the local group, I have suppressed the notification in the task bar with GPO, But windows explorer creates a popup titled "We cant sign into your account"